# What's the type of mapView elements like Marker and MapView, Typescript react native?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, interface

I am using typescript with MapView and its components, I need to know the type of mapView and marker to put in the interface,

That's the code,

```
interface SelectInput {
  style?: StyleProp<ViewStyle>;
  isMapSelector?: boolean;
  isModalVisable?: boolean;

  markerLocation?: MarkerProps ; // What sould I type here
  initialRegion?: MapViewProps; // What sould I type here
  onMapViewOress?: () => object;

  onOpen: () => void;
  onClose: () => void;
}


<MapView
   initialRegion={initialRegion}   //Warining under initialRegion
   onPress={onMapViewOress}
   style={{flex: 1}}>
   <Marker coordinate={markerLocation} /> //Warining under coordinate
</MapView>
```

That's the warning that appears to me under initialRegion is,
"No overload matches this call.
Overload 1 of 2, '(props: MapViewProps | Readonly): MapView', gave the following error.
Type 'MapViewProps | undefined' is not assignable to type 'Region | undefined'.
Type 'MapViewProps' is missing the following properties from type 'Region': latitude, longitude, latitudeDelta, longitudeDelta"

That's the warning that appears to me under coordinate is,
"No overload matches this call.
Overload 1 of 2, '(props: MarkerProps | Readonly): Marker', gave the following error.
Type 'MarkerProps | undefined' is not assignable to type 'LatLng | AnimatedRegion'.
Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'LatLng | AnimatedRegion'."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this help:

```js
interface MarkerProps {
     latitude: number;
     longitude: number;
}

interface MapViewProps {
     latitude: number;
     longitude: number;
     latitudeDelta: number;
     longitudeDelta: number;
}

interface SelectInput {
  // ...
  markerLocation?: MarkerProps;
  initialRegion?: MapViewProps;
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Tahnk you, it solved the proplem in MapViewProps, but in coordinate show that warning, "No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(props: MarkerProps | Readonly<MarkerProps>): Marker', gave the following error.
    Type 'MarkerProps | undefined' is not assignable to type 'LatLng | AnimatedRegion'.
      Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'LatLng | AnimatedRegion'."